# Next without For error in Select Case

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that processes data but skips over data points that meet specific criteria. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
Set gData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("E3:E16")
For Each cell In gData
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case Is = 20
            Next cell 'error thrown here
        Case Is > 20
            'Do stuff
    End Select
Next
```

The compiler is throwing a "Next without For" error in the location noted above. I haven't been able to find a working solution to this problem. Please help!

Comment: Why skip? Just do nothing and let the For Each loop do its thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set gData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("E3:E16")
For Each cell In gData
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case Is > 20
            'Do stuff
    End Select
Next
```